# Shower valve manufacturer identification

Tags: plumbing

Any idea who manufactured this valve and can I get a replacement? It's a shower mixing valve in an old modular house.

[image]

Comment: look carefully for any labels

Comment: Can you unscrew any of the visible parts? Maybe there's a stamping.

Comment: Modular home builders probably used the cheapest of the cheap imported hardware. I'd plan for a full replacement.

Comment: Probably better off replacing the valve assembly.  Looks like a piece of junk.